# How to call a simple javascript file from a custom drupal module

Tags: php, drupal

contemptable newbie here trying to figure out how to integrate javascript with php. I've included

```
<?php
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule').'/test.js');
?>
```

At the top of my custom ".module" file, and I've clearly included test.js in the same module folder. test.js is simply:

```
<script>
function test(){
alert("I am an alert box");
}
</script>
```

And I've tried a bunch of permutations with the tags (including DOCTYPE, head only, head body, etc) but I can't seem to get the darn thing to pop up.

Any ideas about what I may be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

If the code is within a script file, then I don't believe you need the script tags. Those get handled when you print the code out. Try removing them and then running again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try as:-

To add the javascript code in your PHP code, it'd be better to use [drupal_add_js()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7).

The following code adds inline javascript.

```
drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () { alert("Hello!"); });',
array('type' => 'inline', 'scope' => 'footer', 'weight' => 5)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way of adding the javascript code inline with the PHP module.  I write about it [here](http://flashum.com/?q=drupal_blog#simple-table-of-contents-21).  I have not found a good way to show the html here so here is an image instead.

[image]